# vscode terminal not showing a "node" tag when a NodeJs process is running on the terminal instance

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently updated my VS Code app to Version 1.78.1.

Previously, there was a node tag indicating that a NodeJs process was running on the terminal instance, but I can no longer find it in the latest version of VS Code.

Are there any ways to make the node tag reappear as it did before?

[image]

Tried to see the vscode config to see if there are any related fields but haven't been able to find any.